# Auto Redirect if session token already exists in Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I want to redirect to the dashboard if the user is already logged in and the login token is stored in session. I tried `mainView.router.loadPage('dashboard.html?Token='+login_token);` but I'm getting this error:

> *Cannot read property 'router' of undefined*

Answer (score 0):

Your `mainView` is not defined ! You have to declare a view before you can use the router : [Adding view](https://framework7.io/docs/get-started.html#initialize-app)